# Why does my 2D IDFT produce double the expected amplitudes? (FFTW)

Tags: c++, fftw, dft

I am using a complex-to-real 2D IDFT to visualize complex signals as an image. I initialize the complex frequency domain by manually setting modes. However, some modes produce real output that seems to be double what is expected.

My code:

```
int N = 8;
int logical_width = N / 2 + 1; // Logical width of frequency domain data

double* T = new double[N * N];
fftw_complex* F = (fftw_complex*)fftw_alloc_complex(N * logical_width);

fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(N, N, F, T, FFTW_MEASURE);

// Initialize all frequency modes to 0
for (int i = 0; i < N * logical_width; i++) {
    F[i][REAL] = 0.0;
    F[i][IMAG] = 0.0;
}

F[1][REAL] = 16.0; // Set mode k[0, 1]

fftw_execute(plan);

printTime(T, N); // Print time domain to console
```

Output of `printTime()`:
[image: Output of printTime():]

The amplitude of the signal seems to be 32 after the IDFT. However, I would expect it to be 16, given that the only contributing mode is `k[0, 1] = 16 + 0i`.

Why does this happen? Should I transform the signals somehow before executing the IDFT?

Comment: I'm not sure how `printTime()` calculates the amplitude, but consider that a function `a * sin(x)` produces values between `-a` and `a`, so the difference between maximum and minimum is `2 * a`.

Comment: `printTime()` doesn't calculate anything. It just prints the time domain values rounded to 2 decimals. The maximum and minimum values in this case are 32 and -32, even though the input is of the form `16.0 * cos(x)`.

Comment: When doing fft's there is typically a rescale or normalization that needs to occur. I thought it was by `N` though. So I'm not quite understanding something. Take a look at [this](http://www.fftw.org/faq/section3.html#whyscaled) fftw documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying a C2R transform. As I explained in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63993727/7328782), it expects a conjugate symmetric input. You provide half the input, the other half is assumed to be the conjugate symmetric of your input. Thus, you are setting two modes, not one, each with a magnitude of 16. Together they form a sinusoid of amplitude 32.

Note that FFTW’s inverse DFT doesn’t normalize. There are different definitions for the DFT, some put the normalization in the forward transform, some put it in the inverse transform. FFTW doesn’t normalize at all. This leads to IFFT(FFT(f)) = Nf (with N the number of samples). You need to manually normalize somewhere for the equality to hold. Most commonly the inverse transform is normalized. This would lead, in your case, to a sinusoid with an amplitude of 32/N, and is what you would see in most signal processing textbooks. See for example page 7 in [this PDF](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Ebouman/ece438/lecture/module_1/1.6_dft/1.6.2_dft_prop_and_pairs.pdf).

Comment: Hi Cris, thanks for the response once again. I noticed that for some modes, this doubling of the amplitude did not occur. I assume this is the case because they have no conjugate in the frequency domain?

Since I realise my explanation might be a bit poor, I visualized it: https://i.imgur.com/JJPdf67.png

The time domain is n0 by n1. The gray cells are redundant and are not computed by FFTW. The red cells have no conjugate in the time domain. Is that correct?

Comment: @Naemesis Yes, that is right. The red cells are their own conjugate, so to speak, and therefore are expected to be real valued. By the way, for an odd-sized transform, you only have one such column.

Comment: Hi Cris, sorry to bother you again, but I've been struggling with another question related to the complex DFT for a while now. Would you mind taking a look? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64155448/4017363